# python - Replace first five characters in a column with asterisks

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a column called SSN in a CSV file with values like this

```
289-31-9165
```

I need to loop through the values in this column and replace the first five characters so it looks like this

```
***-**-9165
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
emp_file = "Resources/employee_data1.csv"

emp_pd = pd.read_csv(emp_file) 

new_ssn = emp_pd["SSN"].str.replace([:5], "*")

emp_pd["SSN"] = new_ssn
```

How do I loop through the value and replace just the first five numbers (only) with asterisks and keep the hiphens as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Mr. Me, this will instead remove everything before the first 6 characters and replace them with your new format.

```
emp_pd["SSN"] = emp_pd["SSN"].apply(lambda x: "***-**" + x[6:])
```

Comment: @KrithikaRaghavendran,  though  this is good approach but pandas replace() is faster way of achieving this you don't need to call lambda, however you can upvote the answer apart from accepting it :-)  +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with replace() method:

### Example dataframe :

borrows from @AkshayNevrekar..

```
>>> df
           ssn
0  111-22-3333
1  121-22-1123
2  345-87-3425
```

### Result:

```
>>> df.replace(r'^\d{3}-\d{2}', "***-**", regex=True)
           ssn
0  ***-**-3333
1  ***-**-1123
2  ***-**-3425
```

OR

```
>>> df.ssn.replace(r'^\d{3}-\d{2}', "***-**", regex=True)
0    ***-**-3333
1    ***-**-1123
2    ***-**-3425
Name: ssn, dtype: object
```

OR:

```
df['ssn'] = df['ssn'].str.replace(r'^\d{3}-\d{2}', "***-**", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your asterisks in front, then grab the last 4 digits.

```
new_ssn = '***-**-' + emp_pd["SSN"][-4:]
```

Comment: Last 4 should be: `new_ssn = '***-**-' + emp_pd["SSN"][-4:]`

Answer (score 0):

You  can use `regex`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ssn':['111-22-3333','121-22-1123','345-87-3425']})

def func(x):
    return re.sub(r'\d{3}-\d{2}','***-**', x)

df['ssn'] = df['ssn'].apply(func)    

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           ssn                                                                                                                                 
0  ***-**-3333                                                                                                                                 
1  ***-**-1123                                                                                                                                 
2  ***-**-3425
```