# Replace first few digits birthdate pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, replace

**Background**

I have the following sample df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Birthdate':['This person was born Date of Birth: 5/6/1950 and other',
                          'no Date of Birth: nothing here',
                          'One Date of Birth: 01/01/2001 last here'], 
                  'P_ID': [1,2,3],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']} 

                 )

 df
                                 Birthdate                 N_ID P_ID
    0   This person was born Date of Birth: 5/6/1950 a...   A1  1
    1   no Date of Birth: nothing here                      A2  2
    2   One Date of Birth: 01/01/2001 last here             A3  3
```

**Goal**

Replace first few digits birthdate with `*BDAY*` so e.g. `5/6/1950` becomes `*BDAY*1950`

**Desired Output**

```
                                 Birthdate                 N_ID P_ID
    0   This person was born Date of Birth: *BDAY*1950 a... A1  1
    1   no Date of Birth: nothing here                      A2  2
    2   One last Date of Birth: *BDAY*2001 last here        A3  3
```

**Tried**

From [python - Replace first five characters in a column with asterisks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595855/python-replace-first-five-characters-in-a-column-with-asterisks) I have tried the following code:
`df.replace(r'Date of Birth: ^\d{3}-\d{2}', "*BDAY*", regex=True)` but it does not quite give me my desired output

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Birthdate'] = df.Birthdate.str.replace(r'[0-9]?[0-9]/[0-9]?[0-9]/', '*BDAY*')


Out[273]:
                                           Birthdate  P_ID N_ID
0  This person was born Date of Birth: *BDAY*1950...     1   A1
1                     no Date of Birth: nothing here     2   A2
2            One Date of Birth: *BDAY*2001 last here     3   A3
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression might also work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Birthdate':['This person was born Date of Birth: 5/6/1950 and other',
                          'no Date of Birth: nothing here',
                          'One Date of Birth: 01/01/2001 last here'], 
                  'P_ID': [1,2,3],
                  'N_ID' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']} 

                 )
df= df.replace(r'(?i)date\s+of\s+birth:\s+\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/', "Date of Birth: *BDAY*", regex=True)

print(df)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/50jZAV/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/50jZAV/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

#### wrong regex

Your regex looks for 3 digits, then a '-', then 2 digits.  Your example data has 2 digits, a '/', then 2 digits.

Try:

```
df.replace(
    r'(Date of Birth:\s+)\d{2}/\d{2}/',
    r"\1*BDAY*",
    regex=True)
```

Comment: I think that is close. `One *BDAY*/2001 last here` was correctly identified. But `This person was born Date of Birth: 5/6/1950` was missed.

Comment: I adjusted the regex pattern and replacement.  PS. When I tested your regex, it didn't replace anything.